# which framework to do fast development of WEB application using Java

Tags: java, web-applications

There are lots of framework available in market but which framework should be used for fast development of java web application?

Additional to above, Many prefer combination of framework and JS library e.g. gwt/jquery+spring+hibernate; but which combination provide good performance of web application along with less time of web application development.

Comment: *"which framework to do fast development.."*  The one you are really good at using.

Comment: Sounds like you need a better architect on your team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i am concerned , the best J2EE Frameworks are

1.Spring as Applcication Developement Frame work

1. Hibernate for ORM
2. Struts for View

The main thing we have to remember is as an IT professional is don't dependent on any framework.You may need to work on the frame work u really don't know. But have the basic Java concepts in hand, which makes us adoptable to any J2EE framework

Comment: +1 just for "The main thing we have to remember is as an IT professional is don't dependent on any framework... the frame work u really don't know"